# Make all values in range show up on x axis

Tags: python, list, function, graph, matplotlib

Could someone please guide me on how should I make sure that all ticks (or maybe a better way to specify will be to say all elements in the list passed to plot function) are displayed on the x axis when using matplotlib to plot graphs?

```
plt.plot(xValues, meanWeekdayArrivalCounts, 'k-')
```

I want all the values in the list xValues to show up on the graph. By default, only, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 show up.

[image]

Answer (score 35):

Simply add `plt.xticks(xValues)` to your code. Given the number of points in your graph, the labels might clutter.

You could display them as minor ticks if you set them on the axes object with `ax.set_xticks(xValues, minor=True)`.

Comment: How can I ensure that the spacing between the ticks in xValues is equal and not according to the actual value of ticks.

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 1.0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to show all the years in my graph so I did

```
plt.xticks(list(table_05.anio.unique()))
```